# How to disconnect session in opentok?

Tags: javascript, web, opentok

I am using opentok for web and my issue is how to disconnect from current session. I wanna know the steps in detail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You can call [`disconnect`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#disconnect) method on the [`Session`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html) object which is returned by [`OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId)`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initSession).

If you are publishing and call `disconnect`, the `streamDestroyed` event will fire letting other participants in the session know that a stream has been destroyed. After this event, the participants will receive a [`connectionDestroyed`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) event letting them know that a person has "left" the session. However, from the perspective of the publisher, the `sessionDisconnected` event will also fire when the connection is destroyed.

For the `streamDestroyed` event dispatched by the `Session` object, the default behavior is that all Subscriber objects that are subscribed to the stream are unsubscribed and removed from the HTML DOM. Each `Subscriber` object dispatches a destroyed event when the element is removed from the HTML DOM. If you call the `preventDefault()` method in the event listener for the `streamDestroyed` event, the default behavior is prevented and you can clean up Subscriber objects using your own code. For more information, please see: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamEvent.html

If you disconnect, you do not need to call the `unpublish` method because the SDK will take care of the tear down for you.

Comment: Is it possible for the host to disconnect session (without interacting with back end) for all the participants on Andorid/iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from the session (this handles unpublishing media streams).:

```
tokboxVideo.Session.disconnect();
```

Details in here:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#disconnect

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there anything else? I did connect->publish->subscribe for session start. So for the terminate of tok disconnect is surely needed. I wanna know how to order disconnect, unpublish, unsubscribe methods.